# Problem with self sizing Image embedded in NavigationButton. It turns blue

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios13

I have a strange problem, where if an resizable image that I made (a custom view) is not in NavigationButton, then it works normally, but if it is in it, then the image is still sized well, but it becomes fully blue. Does anyone know what is wrong?

```swift
struct DynamicallyResizableImage: View {
    let imageName: String
    let height: CGFloat
    let width: CGFloat

    init(imageName: String, height: CGFloat? = nil, width: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.imageName = imageName
        let imageSize = UIImage(named: imageName)!.size

        guard let height = height else {
            if let width = width {

                self.width = width
                self.height = imageSize.height * (width/imageSize.width)
                return
            }
            self.height = 0
            self.width = 0
            return
        }

        if let width = width {
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            return
        }

        self.height = height
        self.width = imageSize.width * (height/imageSize.height)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
    }

}
```

```swift
NavigationButton(destination: PicturePreviewView(imageName: "IMG_4955")) {
                        DynamicallyResizableImage(imageName: "IMG_4955", height: 200)
                    }
```

When not embedded in NavigationButton, everything works great. When embedded in NavigationButton, the image becomes gets filled with blue color.

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks!!!

Comment: I haven't used SwiftUI at all but if this is anything like a UIBarButtonItem used in a UINavigationBar or UIToolBar from UIKit, then it's because the image is treated as a mask and the current tint color is what appears. See if SwiftUI has some way to indicate that the image should be treated as "original" and not "template".

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the comment! No, normally you use it in List cells (something like UITableView cells), but not limited to I think. Its just a button with action that navigates to a different screen.

Comment: @rmaddy Indeed the problem was in what you described. I had to set the rendering mode to original like I posted in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it with a help of a fellow redditor. Inside off the custom view I had to add a renderingMode to the Image just like that:

```swift
Image(imageName)
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
```

Comment: This is glorious, I had this bug since the seed1, and it was driving me crazy. Maybe Apple need to default image to original, or maybe the NavigationButton behaviour need to change. But this def fix the issue!